# Looking for a super explanation /tkinter direction (getting max recursion depth without super)

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to use my "controller" to call my "view." But if I don't use super, I get an infinite recursion when buildTK tries to build iiBar. Using Super everything is fine. I'd just like to understand why that is.

```
import inputhandler as iH
import buildtk as tA
import scanhandler as aS

class ControlHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.view = tA.buildTK() #does not work

        self.view = super(tA.buildTK) #works
        self.smodel = aS.aScan()
        self.imodel = iH.InputHandler()
```

The buildTK class:

```
import tkinter as tt
import controlhandler as cH

class buildTK(tt.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.frame = tt.Frame(master, bg="tan")
        self.frame.grid()

        self.ibar = iiBar(self.frame)

...
class iiBar:
    def __init__(self, master):
        print(repr(self)) #prints forever
        self.mbar = tt.Frame(master, relief = 'raised', bg="blue")
        self.mbar.grid(column=0, row=0) #Show File Bar
        self.tryFile() 
        self.tryTool()
        self.tryH()
```

EDIT: those try methods have no effect when commented out, but the basic code is:

```
    def tryTool(self):
        # Create  tools menu
        self.toolsbutton = tt.Menubutton(self.mbar, text = 'Tools', )
        self.toolsbutton.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.toolsmenu = tt.Menu(self.toolsbutton, tearoff=0)
        self.toolsbutton['menu'] = self.toolsmenu

        # Populate tools menu
        self.toolsmenu.add('command', label = 'tools', command = root.destroy)
```

And out of curiosity, is there a best-practice for going about what I'm trying to do? Eventually I'd like a "build handler" to instantiate the form (either tkinter, html, xml) - in which case the controller would instantiate the build handler which would determine what to build.

Comment: Part of the issue may be in your buildTK's `__init__` function. In tkinter, you don't want to set an attribute of the inheriting frame to a frame, you want to make the child object _into_ a frame. You do this by calling `tt.Frame.__init__(self, master, **args**)` directly (no self.frame =, or anything.) Your frame probably shouldn't be gridding itself, but that's arbitrary.

Comment: On the rest, can we get tryFile, tryTool, or tryH? If any of those attempt to deal with a buildTK, you could get an issue with buildTK creating an iiBar > iiBar creating a buildTK > ...

Answer (score 1):

Found my issues. Some python oversights.

1. the import seems to take care of the instantiation

part of this has to do with the inconsistency I used at the end of my classes, i.e;

a. #if **name** == "**main**": ControlHandler()
forgot that was commented out

b. buildTK

```
root = tt.Tk()
all = buildTK(root)
root.mainloop()
```

c. buildTK0

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
else: main()
```

Super appreciate the feedback guys! Gave me lots to consider/review!

Answer (score 0):

What you show here is not a good example of inheritance - it is somehwat messed up. The same thing goes for yout attempeted uses of super - it just does not crash because you are not doing anything with the super-object at all, after creating it.

So., first, define if you are inheriting Tkinter components of compositing, having attributes of your classes that reference Tkinter objects. This code snippet:

```
class buildTK(tt.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.frame = tt.Frame(master, bg="tan")
        self.frame.grid()

        self.ibar = iiBar(self.frame)
```

does a little of both. 
I consider (and a lot of the internet) that trying to inherit from a complex GUI class is a waste of time and effort - although OO purists from the 90's thought that tobe a good idea and documented it that way. Tkinter classes have hundreds of methods and attributes - if you try to subclass one of those, your chances of name-clashing sky-rocket, to start with.

Otherwise, if you just don't try to inherit from **any** tkinter component, and just use them, and give-up on your non-use of supe, your app have a nice chance of working -

as for what "super" does: it provides a clean mean to call the method you are overriding in a sublass on its superclasses, respecting Python's method-resolution-order (mro), and without hardcoding the super-class reference inside the method. `super`should be used only for that - for example, if you were to properly inherit tkinter.frame:

```
class buildTK(tt.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super(buildTK, self).__init__(master, bg="tan")
        # this is for composition: self.frame = tt.Frame(master, bg="tan")
        self.grid()
        # a prefix on our attributes and methods avoid clashing with
        # tkinter:
        self._myapp_ibar = iiBar(self.frame)
```

Comment: Your comments about inheriting from "a complex GUI class" don't make much sense to me. A frame isn't particularly complex, and there are good reasons to inherit from it. Namely, to make new widgets that have the same behavior as built-in widgets.  If your goal is to make reusable GUI components, inheriting from `Frame`is the correct way to do it.  That being said, inheriting from Frame _and_ creating a frame internally doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Pick some "GUI" programing guide from about up to 2004. You will see recomendations of making your whole application inheriting from a Window or Frame class - that is the kind of nonsense that still floats around the internet and I prefer to make clear is not the way to go. 
Of course creating an specialized widget would be nice - but not thinking on an app as a "very specialized and super-smart widget".

Comment: What is your main objection from a class inheriting from Frame? What problem does it cause that you think should be avoided?

Comment: The inherent problem is that GUI classes have hundreds of attributes and no resources to avoid name collision - and definitely should not be subclassed by novices. They canbe subclassed by one who knows what he is doing - but event there, while it makes sense to make a specialized widget - let me say again: it is not meant that all of one's program logic is inside a GUI widget subclass. BUT that was the thinking of "OOP development" for a good 10 years more. 
Again:  you have your program logic floating around 100's other name definitions on the same namespace, and no control about that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't fully agree, but I understand where you're coming from.  Our philosophies seem to differ mostly by less than a dozen bytes of code -- is the root window or frame `MyApplication()`, or is it `MyApplication().root_window`? I think both are a perfectly fine way to write tkinter apps, and the choice is more dependent on the overall requirements and complexity of the app rather than dogma.